# Why is the Alt key released and pressed in AutoHotkey's KeyHistory?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an AutoHotkey script that sends the left arrow key when `Alt + A` is pressed. I also enabled KeyHistory.

```
KeyHistory 
!a::Send "{Left 1}"
```

When I open KeyHistory and press `Alt + A`, KeyHistory gives the following output:

[image]

I understand that the `Control` key is used as a masking key, but why is `LAlt` released and then pressed down? Is it because I was originally holding down the LAlt key (to press `Alt + A`), and when the script executes, the script needs to release the LAlt key before pressing the left key? I think this may be the case, because there could be problems if the LAlt was kept in the down state (in this case, sending `Alt + left` instead of `left`).

I'm guessing that after the `left` key is sent, the script then presses down `LAlt` again, since I'm still holding down the `LAlt` key.

Is my hypothesis correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has the trigger of `!a::` and not `!a up::`,
which means that this is to be triggered when the keys are
pressed down, not after they are released.
This means that, if left as is, when the <kbd>Left</kbd> key is sent
the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key would still be pressed down.

The problem that AutoHotkey is trying to avoid here is that
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Backspace</kbd>,
which should certainly be avoided.

This forces AHK to release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key before it
emulates the pressing and release of the <kbd>Left</kbd> key.

After the <kbd>Left</kbd> key is sent, AHK will then emulate
again the pressing of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, so when you later
physically release the key the situation will be correct.

Note that AHK does not know or care about
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> being the same as <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
This is a general mechanism that is there to avoid all kinds of
unwanted key combinations that could be caused by leaving the
<kbd>Alt</kbd> key in the "down" state.